# I converted a windows 10 64-bit dynamic disk to basic disk and now it will not boot

Tags: windows-10, bsod, mbr, dynamic-disk

I converted my dynamic disk to basic using Aemei Pro, and when restart I get blue screen error message 0xc000000e.

Following advice on this help page, here:

https://www.aomeitech.com/forum/discussion/8051/help-i-convert-window-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk-and-it-break-my-pc?

I created a WinPE USB using AOMEI Partition Assistant Professional, and am attaching a screenshot of Disk Management.

I have tried rebuilding MBR, and also converting the C: partition to primary and active.  I still get the same message.  Can you please advise how to fix this.

Disk 2 is primary.  Disk 5 is a clone I made to try and preserve data from Disk 2.

[image]

Disk 2 was originally a GPT basic disk, then I converted it to Dynamic as I was hoping to extend it onto a new hard drive.  Then, I used Aoemei to convert it back to a basic disk, and then when the computer restarted after the  conversion is when I got that boot error.  Disk 5 is an external HD, I made a clone of disk 2 onto Disk 5 using Aoemei PE USB to create a copy of my files, in case I lose my data on disk 2.  When trying to boot from Disk 5 I get the same exact error message.

Before I did the original Dynamic to Basic conversion, I created a system image using Aoemei Backupper, just in case something went wrong.  But the problem is, I saved the system image onto a dynamic disk, which is comprised of diss 0 + 1.  So using Aoemei restore PE USB, I cannot access the iso file to restore disk 2, as the restoration iso is on that dynamic disk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot use my computer since the conversion.

Comment: Too many conversions to guess in what state are now your disks. If no one suggests a solution, you'll need to install Windows from scratch. Next time, better store the AOMEI backup image on a USB.

Comment: In my experience you cannot convert dynamic to basic. You need to back up the data and remake the disc as basic

Comment: You say the disk was originally GPT. Is it GPT now? If not, that's a problem. You have two options: Convert to GPT or use legacy booting (CSM), if at all possible.

Comment: It is not clear the current state of your disk.  Your screenshot is also unreadable. I personally cannot make easily out the text in the screenshot.  What I see is the disk is now MBR, which means, you cannot boot in UEFI mode.  You cannot easily convert (without data loss), from GPT to MBR, but that also isn't what you claim you did.  So was your disk orignally MBR or GPT?